# Describing element in geodatabase using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, walk, describe-object

With help from people on this site, I have the following code to look for all of the element types in the geodatabase and put them into a report.

```
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, topdown=True)
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
        for filename in filenames:
            desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            elements[desc['dataType']].append(desc)

report = ""

for element_type, element_list in elements.items():
    report += "{}:\n".format(element_type)
    for element_description in element_list:
        report += 
ntpath.basename("\t\t{}\n".format(element_description['featureClassType']))
```

Now I want to describe each of the element in detail. For example, if I want to include in the report what shape type (point/line/polygon/annotation) each feature class in the geodatabase is, I think I can use featureClassType, but I still do not understand how I can put it in to the code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code already describes the data. You now need to extract the shapeType from the Describe object. This is simply:

```
type = desc.shapeType
```

Why create the second set of for loops? Why not build your report as you're iterating through the workspace?  Something like the following (untested) code:

```
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, topdown=True)
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
        for filename in filenames:
            desc = arcpy.da.Describe(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
            featureClassType = desc.dataType
            shapetype = desc.shapeType
            #Do something here to write to your report
```

Comment: if desc.datasetType=='FeatureClass': shapetype = desc.shapeType # for safety, arcpy.da.Walk returns tables and rasters as well, for these dataset types their matching describe object properties do not contain shapeType https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q30000001w000000